# How to import environment variables nicely into documented functions?

Tags: r

I'm working on developing an R package, using:

```
pkgs <- c("devtools", "testthat", "roxygen2", "configr")

pkgs_miss <- pkgs[which(!pkgs %in% utils::installed.packages()[, 1])]
  if (length(pkgs_miss) > 0) {
    utils::install.packages(pkgs_miss)
  }
```

My file structure looks like this:

```
/ mypackage
    / inst
        /conf
           * config.yml, env_conf.R

    / man
    / packrat
    / R
      * myfun1.R, myfun2.R
    / tests
```

For clarity and transparency, I'm trying to keep all environment variable in `env_conf.R` (and `config.yml`)  where I'm importing those environment variable from `.Renviron` via `config.yml` which looks like:

```
production:
  USERNAME: Sys.getenv("MYUSERNAME")
  PASSWORD: Sys.getenv("MYPASSWORD")
  HOST: Sys.getenv("MYHOST")
```

Further, I'm importing those environment variables into `env_conf.R`:

```
configuration <- configr::read.config(system.file('inst/conf', 'config.yml', package='mypackage'))

USERNAME <– eval(parse(text = configuration$production$USERNAME))
PASSWORD <– eval(parse(text = configuration$production$PASSWORD))
HOST <– eval(parse(text = configuration$production$HOST))
```

Now, I would like to use those variables in my function myfun1 in myfun1.R in the following way, either from `env_conf.R` or `config.yml`:

```
#' Query MySQL Database
#' @param some_statement 
#' @return sql output
#' @importFrom DBI dbConnect dbGetQuery 
#' @export
myfun1 <- function(some_statement){
  con <- DBI::dbConnect(
    RMySQL::MySQL(),
    username = USERNAME,
    password = PASSWORD,
    host = HOST,
    port = 3306
  )
  result <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, some_statement)
  result
}
```

Is it possible somehow to import those Variables given the required context into myfun1.R?
I have tried, without success,  to use different combinations of `system.file('inst/conf', 'env_conf.R', package='mypackage')` within the documented function myfun1,which mostly results in `'' No such of file.`

However do not know whether there are more concise ways. Appreciate any insights!